# How to do LINQ Cross Join With Dot Notation

Tags: c#, linq, syntax, linq-to-objects

I know how to write a query notation join in dot notation, but how do you write a cross join in dot notation?

```
    List<Alpha> als = new List<Alpha>{new Alpha(), new Alpha()};
    List<Bravo> bros = new List<Bravo>{new Bravo(), new Bravo()};

    //so far so good.
    var res = from a in als
              from b in bros
              select new { A = a, B = b };

    var what = res.ToArray();

    //hmmmm.  Not so sure.
    var result = als.Join(bros, null, null, (x, y) => new { X = x, Y = y });
```

Another way of asking this question: when the C# compiler invisibly converts cross-join query notation into dot notation, what does that dot notation look like?

Comment: It would help to learn how the translation from the query syntax to the "dot notation" is made. Once you understand that, then this should be cake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its

```
als.SelectMany(x => bros, (a, b) => new {A = a, B = b});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 als.SelectMany(a => bros.Select(b =>  new {A = a, B = b}));
```

Answer (score -1):

It should look something like this:

```
var res = als.Join(bros,
    alsItem => alsItem.IdToJoin,
    brosItem => brosItem.OtherId,
    (alsItem, brosItem) => {X = alsItem, Y = brosItem});
```

Comment: That would be an inner join.